# java: timezone getTimeZone("GMT-0700")' timezone useDaylight incorrect

Tags: java, timezone, dst, timezone-offset

I want to get the time zone information for Los Angeles, now 10/10/2017 is daylight saving time,
But I got a different result when I got the time zone in Los Angeles in two ways.

```
public class TimeZoneDemo2 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    TimeZone timeZoneLosAngeles = 
    TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles");
    System.out.println(timeZoneLosAngeles);

    TimeZone timeZoneGmtMinus07 = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-07:00");
    System.out.println(timeZoneGmtMinus07);
  }
}
```

the result is:

> sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="America/Los_Angeles",offset=-28800000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=185,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=America/Los_Angeles,offset=-28800000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=3,startMonth=2,startDay=8,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=7200000,startTimeMode=0,endMode=3,endMonth=10,endDay=1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=7200000,endTimeMode=0]]
>
> sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="GMT-07:00",offset=-25200000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null]

My question is: Information about daylight saving time in time zone information obtained by "America/Los_Angeles". Why not include daylight saving time information (useDaylight = false) in the time zone information obtained by "GMT -0700"?

Comment: Your implication that the result of `TimeZone.getTimeZone(String)` depends upon the current time is incorrect.

Comment: There is multiple locations which are GMT-7 http://www.mapstudio.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/9781770265646.jpg how would it know you meant the one for Los Angeles?

Comment: `GMT-07:00` is an **offset** (difference from UTC), while `America/Los_Angeles` is a **timezone** (set of all offsets a region uses during history), read more about the difference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info). As already said, there's more than 1 timezone [that uses the same offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UTC_time_offsets#UTC.E2.88.9207:00.2C_T), so only by having GMT-7, you [can't say which timezone is](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36629250/7605325)

Answer (score 9):

> I want to get the time zone information for Los Angeles, now 10/10/2017 is daylight saving time

So you should ask for the "America/Los_Angeles" zone. That's what it's there for.

The "GMT-07:00" zone is a fixed-offset zone - it's only suitable when you want to represent "a time zone which is permanently seven hours behind UTC". That *doesn't* apply to Los Angeles.

There are plenty of other time zones which are *sometimes* at UTC-7 - why would you expect GMT-07:00 to mean "the time zone observed in Los Angeles"?

In other words, Java is doing the right thing - it's your expectations of what the "GMT-07:00" zone means that are incorrect.

Comment: Moreover, Los Angeles is UTC-8 for part of the year; if you expect Java to guess you mean an Olsen id when you use GMT-7, how does it know you don't mean Denver? (Or anywhere else which uses -7 for part of the year).

Comment: ...or Phoenix, which is -7 for the *entire* year.

Answer (score 0):

The [Answer by Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46660839/642706) is correct and should be accepted. You cannot reliably determine a time zone from an offset-from-UTC as many zones may share an offset coincidentally. Also, the offset for a zone likely varies over time.

Here are some code samples addressing the issue using more modern classes than that seen in the Question.

## java.time

You are using troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

As others stated, if you know the intended time zone, always use that zone in preference to a mere [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset). An offset is simply a number of hours, minutes, and seconds ahead of, or behind, UTC. A time zone is a history of changes to the offset used by the people of a region. A time zone knows the past, present, and (tentatively) the future of such changes in offset.

The `ZoneId` and `ZoneOffset` classes replace `TimeZone`.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Los_Angeles" ) ;  // Or "Africa/Tunis", "Pacific/Auckland", etc.
```

Get the current moment as seen through the lens of that zone.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;  // Fetch current moment for that zone.
```

Extract that same moment but adjusted into UTC.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;  // Extract the same moment but in UTC.
```

Adjust that some moment into another zone.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtKolkata = instant.atZone( ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ) ;  // Determine same moment, same point on timeline, but in another time zone.
```

All three of these objects represent the very same simultaneous point on the timeline, but viewed with a different wall-clock time.

See the offset used by the people of that region at that moment.

```
ZoneOffset offset = z.getRules().getOffset( instant ) ;  // Get the offset in place at that moment for that time zone.
```

You will find that for 2018, in part of that year the offset for `America/Los_Angeles` will be `-07:00` (sever hours behind UTC). In the other part of the year, the offset will be `-08:00` (eight hours behind UTC). This change in offset is due to politicians’ decision to observe [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time).

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).