# Is there a Way to Get TZ Database Name from Python Pendulum Given Offset?

Tags: python-3.x, iso8601, timezone-offset, pendulum

Python Pendulum Mavens,

In Python, when using the [awesome] date & time manipulation package, **Pendulum**, how can `tzinfo` (TZ Database Name; such as 'Europe/London', 'Australia/Melbourne', etc.) be determined based on, or as a function of, `UTC Offset`?

- For example: Given an Offset of (say) `-07:00`, how could
  'America/Los_Angeles' be derived?

Or, is it necessary to set `tz='America/Los_Angeles'`?

Many thanks for any assistance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get time zone name from an offset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36629250/how-to-get-time-zone-name-from-an-offset)

Comment: It is an impossible task.  There are 20 different canonical time zones (see [the list here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)) that have an offset of `-07:00` at one point or another.  Please read "Time Zone != Offset" in  [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, Matt! Very informative!